# Sort a list of vectors by a particular index

Tags: r, sorting

Given the following list :

```r
l = list(
  c('first', 5),
  c('second',3),
  c('third',2)
)
```

Which is

```
> l
[[1]]
[1] "first" "5"    

[[2]]
[1] "second" "3"     

[[3]]
[1] "third" "2"
```

How best to sort the elements of the list based on the second elements within
the elements. By this I mean that I have

```
  c('first', 5),
  c('second',3),
  c('third',2)
```

And would like to have the ordering based on `5,3,2`, giving

```
  c('third',2)
  c('second',3),
  c('first', 5),
```

One approach would be :

```
x=as.double(sapply(l, function(x) x[2]))
l[order(x)]
```

I'm not sure if there's a better approach though.

Answer (score 4):

An option is to extract the 2nd element with `[`, convert to `numeric`, `order` and use the index for ordering the `list` 'l'

```
l[order(as.numeric(sapply(l, `[`, 2)))]
```

Or `unlist`, then extract the 2nd element with a recycling logical index, convert to `numreic` and `order`

```
l[order(as.numeric(unlist(l)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))]
```

Or using a faster approach with `vapply`

```
l[order(as.numeric(vapply(l, `[`, 2, FUN.VALUE = character(1))))]
```

---

Or with `map` and `pluck`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_chr(l, pluck, 2) %>%
      as.integer %>%
      order %>% 
      l[.]
```

Comment: thanks, I'm not sure what the advantage of this is over the solution i gave in the original post though

Comment: @baxx This uses the extraction without anonymous function, but I don't know what would qualify as a. better approach for you

Comment: i haven't actually seen this usage before, `sapply(l, `[`, 2))`, but have only seen it with anon functions. Are you able to summarise what's going on there please?

Comment: ( reading the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.99.17.2/topics/Sapply) suggests that it should have a function, or at least that's my reading )

Comment: @baxx Here we are using the `[` (`?Extract`) to extract the elements based on index.  As it is a `list` of vectors, using the `[`, with the index extracts the nth element i.e. `v1 <- c(3, 5, 7); `[`(v1, 3)#[1] 7`. Note there is backquotes on `[`.  It is doing the `v1[3]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data frame can help you somewhat, i.e.

```
l[order(as.numeric(data.frame(l)[2,]))]
```

which gives

```
> l[order(as.numeric(data.frame(l)[2,]))]
[[1]]
[1] "third" "2"    

[[2]]
[1] "second" "3"     

[[3]]
[1] "first" "5"
```